# What are the ratelimits for GitHub Pages sites?

Tags: github, github-pages, rate-limiting

How many times can you GET request to a GitHub Pages (.github.io) site in a particular amount of time before you get ratelimited by GitHub?
I couldn't find this online anywhere, strangely.

Comment: What kind of data are you planning to host there that you think might be subject to rate limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no limits on requests, there is a limit on the amount of traffic per month - 100 GB. After that Github can stop serving the site.

Comment: It'd be useful to offer a citation to back up this claim. Can you provide a link to GitHub documentation supporting this?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages usage limitations and rate limiting are documented here.  https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#usage-limits

At the time of this answer

> GitHub Pages sites have a soft bandwidth limit of 100 GB per month.